# Jquery slideToggle font issue on Linux Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I've a Jquery slideToggle font issue on Linux Firefox (Lubuntu 14, FF 33). I've not this issue with Chrome or on Windows.

During slideToggle animation, first characters of each line in div.ccn are moved few pixels on the left.
It seems to be related to Firefox font rendering and to browser vertical scrollbar. Bug can occurs when scrollbar have to appear or disappear during slideToggle animation. But it can also be reproduced in other contexts.

Just find some ways to fix it :

1. set p tag padding to 0
2. Replace picture link by a text link
3. Set position:relative to div.ccn

Here a screenshot during animation (first letters are moved few pixel on the left, more visible with real animation) :
[image]

Here after animation (ok) :
[image]

HTML source :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ct">
            <p>
            Nam aliquet ac velit non facilisis. Donec eu eros sit amet tortor tincidunt tincidunt. In at dictum dui. Ut ultricies at nisl ac imperdiet. Ut arcu nibh, aliquam pulvinar pellentesque non, blandit eu justo. Quisque sollicitudin dui a tristique ultricies. Duis at risus dictum, porta mi sed, dictum nisl.
            </p>

            <div class="ccn">
            <p>
            Nam aliquet ac velit non facilisis. Donec eu eros sit amet tortor tincidunt tincidunt. In at dictum dui. Ut ultricies at nisl ac imperdiet. Ut arcu nibh, aliquam pulvinar pellentesque non, blandit eu justo. Quisque sollicitudin dui a tristique ultricies. Duis at risus dictum, porta mi sed, dictum nisl.
            </p>

            <p>
            Nam aliquet ac velit non facilisis. Donec eu eros sit amet tortor tincidunt tincidunt. In at dictum dui. Ut ultricies at nisl ac imperdiet. Ut arcu nibh, aliquam pulvinar pellentesque non, blandit eu justo. Quisque sollicitudin dui a tristique ultricies. Duis at risus dictum, porta mi sed, dictum nisl.
            </p>
            </div>

            <p><a href="javascript:;" class="ccl"><img src="img/com-shw.png" /></a></p>
        </div>

        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">          
            $(".ccn").hide();
            $(".ccl").click(function () {
                $(".ccn").slideToggle(5000);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS source :

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 .5em 0;
}

div.ct {
    width: 640px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

JSFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/f1wjrLfn/
On JSFiddle, result is not the same: j letter of justo word is partially hidden by white hover during slideToggle.

Somebody is aware about this font issue on Linux Firefox ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is due to the scrollbars appearing and shifting the content of the div then all you have to do to fix it is:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No the content does not move around, only the first character of each line in the ccn div.

Comment: Yes, this is another way to fix this issue. But it does not explain the reason why first character of each line move few pixel on the left. From my point of view, it's related to some rendering issue of Fonts in Firefox for Linux. Because I don't get the issue on Firefox for Windows.